# pthread_mutex_timedlock use from Linux assembly language

Tags: c, linux, assembly, pthreads

### The setting:

I am trying to use `pthread_mutex_timedlock` function from `pthreads` in my 32 bit assembly language program. The code looks following way:

```
struct timespec
  .tv_sec  dd ?   ; time in seconds
  .tv_nsec dd ?   ; time is nano seconds
ends

;....
.time timespec  ; the timespec structure
;....
; the code where pthread_mutex_timedlock is used

    mov     eax, [.timeout] ; the timeout in [ms]
    mov     ecx, 1000
    cdq
    div     ecx           ; the timeout in eax [s]
    imul    edx, 1000000  ; the remainder in edx [ns]

    mov     [.time.tv_sec], eax
    mov     [.time.tv_nsec], edx

    lea     eax, [.time]
    cinvoke pthread_mutex_timedlock, [.ptrMutex], eax
    test    eax, eax
    jnz     .error
```

The problem is that the `pthread_mutex_timedlock` function locks the mutex only if it is immediately unlocked.

If the mutex is locked in this moment, the function `pthread_mutex_timedlock` returns immediately with `ETIMEDOUT` error, without waiting for timeout, ignoring the values set in the `timespec` structure.

### The question:

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use a debugger and/or ltrace to see how it's invoked. Also, post a [MCVE] so we can also try it without having to spend time to make your snippet runnable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timeout for `pthread_mutex_timedlock()` is an *absolute* timeout, not relative - it's returning immediately because the absolute time represented by your timeout value has passed long ago.

If you want a "timeout in N milliseconds from now" (a relative timeout), you need to get the current time with `clock_gettime()` (specifying the `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock, as that's the clock used by `pthread_mutex_timedlock()`) then offset it by N milliseconds and pass the result to `pthread_mutex_timedlock()`.

Comment: Yes exactly! It is very, very counter intuitive. :( Also, there is a not obvious handling of the timespec fields. One need to carry the ns field on 1e9 ns.